# How do I get a a specific value from a text file and a XML file? AutomationAnywhere A360

Tags: xml, pdf, text-files, rpa, automationanywhere

I have two problems in AutomationAnywhere A360.

1. Get a specific value from a PDF (I could convert the pdf into a text file)

I have an invoice in PDF format.
In addition, I have an Excel list with departments and their abbreviations which should but do not have to appear in this invoice.
The location of the department name in the invoice is not fixed, and can be arbitrary.

Is it possible to match the Excel list against the PDF to get the following condition
Department in Invoice PDF = Department which is stored in SAP;
if no, then replace the department in SAP with the department stored in Excel list.

2. Get a specific value out of a XML file.

I have an XML file from which I need to extract certain values. The values can always be in different places, but always have the same header.

As an example.
[showing the headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNPEN.png)
Invoice date must be read out.
Header = StartDateTime
Shortly thereafter comes the date that must be read out. (=20230626)

I have a hard time because the data is not always in the same line and also many unnecessary text between the data and partly in the same lines as the data is.

Do you have an idea how I can filter out the specific values?

Thanks a lot guys!

Only got the whole line of the XML with the action text file: get text